# What is a good way to measure how well a set of data fits to a set of functions

Tags: pca

I got a set of data sets as reference data, each comprised of 14 non-independent variables that is to be used as a basis for developing a method to compute data of that kind with fewer computational resources. So basically a set of points in 14-dimensional space.

What I need to do is parametrize my new method so that the output data, again points in 14-dimensional space, fits the reference data as well as possible.

I've done a Principal component analysis, which reduced my 14-dimensional point cloud to a set of 5 linear functions that contain 98% of the variance of my reference data.

What I'm looking for now is a way to generate some kind of measure that tells me how well the new data fits to the reference data, either using the original data set or the PCA-derived linear functions.

And this is where my knowledge ends right now, so I would be grateful for pointers towards good methods to derive such a "how well does the new data fit the reference data" measure of any kind that I can use as benchmark for my parameters.

Comment: I am not sure what the PCA gets you, in this situation, because the linear combinations may require all 14 variables.

Comment: What kind of measure are you looking for beyond the 98% returned by the PCA procedure itself? @Peter In this case PCA allows the data to be recreated fairly accurately in terms of just five variables, rather than 14, together with a (fixed) $14\times 5$ matrix to transform them into 14 seemingly different variables. The PCA results tell us this works well, so the remaining issues concern goodness of fit: is this linear description of the data accurate? Are there outliers? How well might this work for reconstructing or simulating data in the future?

Answer (score 2):

There are a variety of ways of measuring distance in multi-dimensional space. One, for example, generalizes Euclidean distance:

$d_E = \sum (y_i - x _i)^2$

another takes absolute values instead of squaring.

But, since you say your variables may be dependent, perhaps Mahlanobis distance would suit your situation better?

$d_m = (x-\mu)'S^{-1}(x-\mu)$

Where x is a vector in n-dimensional space, $\mu$ is a vector of means and S is the covariance matrix.

Statistical packages ought to be able to do this for you.

Comment: PCA already does these calculations: it has reported (in slightly disguised form) the Euclidean distance if it was performed with the covariance matrix, and otherwise it has reported a quantity proportional to the Mahalanobis distance if it was performed with the correlation matrix.

Comment: @whuber Those measures are surely used by PCA. Getting them out of the output might be tricky if one is not used to this sort of thing, and the right way of doing it must depend on software.

Comment: I believe the 98% does the trick. Of course it's not an absolute measure, but for a given dataset, it's equivalent to what you propose. In other words, it seems your answer is really saying "use the 98% value for your measure of fit."